# 95 percentile hourly data per day in HP Vertica

Tags: vertica

I was attempting to find the 95 percentile of all the values per hour and display them at daily level. Here is snippet of the code I am working on:

```
select distinct columnA
,date(COLLECTDATETIME) as date_stamp
,hour(COLLECTDATETIME) as hour_stamp
,PERCENTILE_DISC(0.95) WITHIN GROUP(order by PARAMETER_VALUE)
over (PARTITION BY hour(COLLECTDATETIME)) as max_per_day
from TableA
where 
columnA = 'abc'
and PARAMETER_NAME = 'XYZ';
```

Right now the result set gives me the same value per hour each day, but it doesn't the 95 percentile value for a given hour per day.

Comment: Please add some test data, actual and desired results...

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but have you tried converting PARAMETER_VALUE into one of the data types that are accepted by the ORDER BY expression (INTEGER, FLOAT, INTERVAL, or NUMERIC)?

For example, you could try WITHIN GROUP(order by PARAMETER_VALUE::FLOAT).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an aggregate query on the top of the subquery (the percentile). Either max/min (because in each scope the percentiles are the same)  `percentile_disc` is an analytics function but not aggregate function

```
SELECT dateid,
       hour,
       MAX(max_per_day) as max_per_day
FROM (
      SELECT date(COLLECTDATETIME) AS dateid,
             hour(COLLECTDATETIME) AS hour,
             percentile_disc(0.95) WITHIN GROUP(order by PARAMETER_VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY date(COLLECTDATETIME), hour(COLLECTDATETIME)) as max_per_day
      WHERE ......

     )
GROUP BY dateid, hour
```